# Low call rate of OpenGL callback functions?(glutDisplayFunc & glutIdleFunc)

Tags: c++, opengl, callback

I got a strange problem regarding OpenGL. I downloaded a OpenGL project(program) just to use it as a sample code on how to setup freeglut and glew.

The first thing i did (after initialising OGL and "connecting" callbacks in **my** program according to the one I downloaded) was to implement an FPS counter. This FPS counter was also copied over to the downloaded OGL program to be able to compare FPS. I've emptied the displayfunc (the callback) in the downloaded program to make it do exactly the same thing (just calculate FPS) as the one i've implemented.

This is now the only thing that happens in both (mine and the downloaded one) programs glutDisplayFunc:

```
int j = 0;
void DisplayCallbackFunc()
{
    CalculateFPS();
    j++;
}
```

The FPS function looks like this:

```
int m_frame = 0;
int m_currtime = 0;
int m_timebase = 0;
char* m_title = new char[24];

void CalculateFPS()
{
    /*Calculate FPS values and outputs avg. fps in the titlebar*/
    m_frame++;
    //get the current time..
    m_currtime = glutGet(GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME);
    //check if a second has passed..
    if (m_currtime - m_timebase > 1000) 
    {
        sprintf(m_title, "Smoke   FPS: %4.0f", m_frame*1000.0f/(m_currtime-m_timebase));
        glutSetWindowTitle(m_title);
        m_timebase = m_currtime;
        m_frame = 0;
    }
}
```

I also have a Idle callback function that only calls glutPostRedisplay().

My problem is that my frames(m_frame) (in FPS counter func in **my** program) increases much slower than the ones in the downloaded program. This also result in a lower FPS. And the difference is quite big;

Downloaded program prints ~ 10 000 000

My program prints ~ 60 000

So I added a counter in the DisplayCallback function (in both programs) and if I break after one sec (breakpoint inside "if" in FPS function) the counter in the downloaded program is much bigger than my counter (8 000 000 vs 50 000).

So my question(s);

Does this mean that the call rate of the callback function in the downloaded program is higher than the one in my program?

And in that case what are the possible reasons for this and wouldn't this mean that **my** program will perform worse than the downloaded one?

Comment: If you get 60 fps, this most likely means that you're rendering at the display refresh rate. That's actually mostly what you want. It doesn't really make sense to render frames that don't show up on the display. Why your program behaves differently than the one you're comparing to is unclear based on what you posted here. There must be some kind of difference in the setup. If you systematically compare the code, you should be able to figure out what it is.

Comment: @RetoKoradi Alright I understand the display refresh rate part and guess that 60 FPS is "normal". But lets say I put a update function(that would update maybe the position of something on the screen) of some kind in my DisplayFunc? Wouldn't that mean that my update function would run less often than the one in the downloaded program? 
And regarding the code comparison; i've tried to **copy** the downloaded code over to my program and still the same result, which leaves the projects settings..